# Using pandas .shift on multiple columns with different shift lengths

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I have created a function that parses through each column of a dataframe, shifts up the data in that respective column to the first observation (shifting past '-'), and stores that column in a dictionary. I then convert the dictionary back to a dataframe to have the appropriately shifted columns. The function is operational and takes about 10 seconds on a 12x3000 dataframe. However, when applying it to 12x25000 it is extremely extremely slow. I feel like there is a much better way to approach this to increase the speed - perhaps even an argument of the shift function that I am missing. Appreciate any help.

```
def create_seasoned_df(df_orig):
    """
    Creates a seasoned dataframe with only the first 12 periods of a loan
    """
    df_seasoned = df_orig.reset_index().copy()
    temp_dic = {}
    for col in cols:
        to_shift = -len(df_seasoned[df_seasoned[col] == '-'])
        temp_dic[col] = df_seasoned[col].shift(periods=to_shift)
    df_seasoned = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dic, orient='index').T[:12]
    return df_seasoned
```

Comment: can you post sample dataframe and expected output from that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code with `apply` instead:

```
def create_seasoned_df(df_orig):
    df_seasoned = df_orig.reset_index().apply(lambda x: x.shift(df_seasoned[col].eq('-').sum()), axis=0)
    return df_seasoned
```